# Error: 'name' is required. on post request from postman using form data

Tags: node.js, postman

[image: error picture of postman]
**.required() function is used for name, price, quantity in post request from node js. if i remove required function then it works correctly.**
**Code of model file:**

```
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  quantity: Number,
});
var Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

function validateProduct(data) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    price: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
    quantity: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
  });
```

**Code of api file**

```
router.post(
      "/",
      validateProduct,
      upload.single("productImage"),
      async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.file);
        let product = await Product.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
        if (product)
          return res.status(400).send("Product with same name already exist!");
        product = new Product();
        product.name = req.body.name;
        product.price = req.body.price;
        product.quantity = req.body.quantity;
        await product.save();
        return res.send(product);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Try to `console.log() req.body` and see what it holds. Are you correctly parsing form-data?

Comment: Did you include the full code of `validateProduct` function ? I think there must be `schema.validate` & `next()` somewhere if you use it as middleware

Comment: yes i have.  `return schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false });`

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few problems :

- Firstly, you're using `validateProduct` as middleware in POST "/" route. So, the function should have `(req, res, next)` as parameters. I'm not sure why it can work when you remove the required function in the JOI schema. In my test, I rewrite it as :

```
function validateProduct(req, res, next) {
     
    // to check the value of req.body
    console.log(req.body);

     // create schema object
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        price: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
        quantity: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
    }).required();

    // schema options
    const options = {
        abortEarly: false, // include all errors
        allowUnknown: true, // ignore unknown props
        stripUnknown: true // remove unknown props
    };

    // validate request body against schema
    const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body, options);

    if (error) {
        // on validate failed
        req.validationError = true;
        next();
    } else {
        // on success replace req.body with validated value and trigger next middleware function
        req.body = value;
        next();
    }
}
```

- Secondly, the `req.body` isn't fully populated before calling the `upload` middleware. You need to put the `validateProduct` middleware after `upload`. (I added `console.log(body)` in the `validateProduct` function above, you can see the difference in the 2 cases.)

```
app.post(
    "/",
    upload.single("productImage"),
    validateProduct,
    async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.file);

        if (req.validationError) {
            // validation failed
            fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path); // need require("fs") at the top of file
            return res.status(400).send("Parameters is not valid!");
        }


        let product = await Product.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
        if (product) {
            return res.status(400).send("Product with same name already exist!");
        }
        product = new Product();
        product.name = req.body.name;
        product.price = req.body.price;
        product.quantity = req.body.quantity;
        await product.save();
        return res.send(product);
    }
);
```

- Finally (optional), because we already upload the file before validating the other fields, we need to remove the file if the requirements are not met.